# MongoDB query to get field that has string array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am making use of dataset

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rashida048/Datasets/master/movie_dataset.csv

I need the below

1. List of top 5 production houses (by budget) and list their top 5 most popular movies, their revenue and vote_average.
2. List of the production house for every year from 2000-2016 which has released the most number of movies in that year.

However, when I query the `production_companies` field the data looks a little odd. Wonder if my import was incorrect. Not sure how I can get the result for the above ask.

```
db.movie_dataset.find({}, {'production_companies' : 1 , '_id' : 0 }).limit(2).pretty();
{
    "production_companies" : "[{\"name\": \"Walt Disney Pictures\", \"id\": 2}, {\"name\": \"Jerry Bruckheimer Films\", \"id\": 130}, {\"name\": \"Second Mate Productions\", \"id\": 19936}]"
}
{
    "production_companies" : "[{\"name\": \"Ingenious Film Partners\", \"id\": 289}, {\"name\": \"Twentieth Century Fox Film Corporation\", \"id\": 306}, {\"name\": \"Dune Entertainment\", \"id\": 444}, {\"name\": \"Lightstorm Entertainment\", \"id\": 574}]"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked the csv, it looks the header is not named to be marked as embedded document.

To be imported as embedded document, the header should be marked as `production_companies.name`, `production_companies.id` in csv. Which is how it's not mentioned here. Hence during import the field `production_companies` has been imported as string.

Either you can set the header properly in csv and then import or update the `production_companies` fields using below code in mongo shell.

For mongosh v5.0

```
db.movies.find({}).forEach((d) => { 
    db.movies.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, 
       { $set: { production_companies: JSON.parse(d.production_companies) } });
 })
```

For mongo shell v4.4

```
cursor = db.collection.find();
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
   var d = cursor.next();
   db.movies.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, 
       { $set: { production_companies: JSON.parse(d.production_companies) } 
}
```

[Documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.4/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/)

Comment: I am using `MongoDB shell version v4.4.0`. Getting a syntax error `uncaught exception: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data :
@(shell):3:40
DBQuery.prototype.forEach@src/mongo/shell/query.js:512:9`

Comment: Code: `db.movie_dataset.find({}).forEach((d) => { 
    db.movie_dataset.updateOne({ _id: d._id }, 
       { $set: { production_companies: JSON.parse(d.production_companies) } });
});`